# Time based Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, pagination, will-paginate, kaminari

I am actually looking for a gem that provides time based pagination.
Like I have payments table, which have :payment_schaduled_on field.
And admin wants to see the entries divided on weekly bases.
Like 
Payments between Time.now and Time.now+1.week.

Does any pagination gem provides this type of pagination or I have to create my own.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not yet, I just made it hand stitched using Offset.